# JavaFX CornerRadiiConverter - Where is it?

Tags: css, javafx, styleable

I'm trying to create a styleable property of type `CornerRadii`, which requires a `StyleConverter` to create the `CssMetaData`. It would be great if the `StyleablePropertyFactory` provided support for `CornerRadii` in the same way as for `Paint`, `Insets`, etc., but because it doesn't a custom solution is required. An internet search yielded [Oracle API 'CornerRadiiConverter'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/CornerRadiiConverter.html) that looks like exactly what I need. The only problem is that it doesn't exist in the JDK I'm using (JDK 10.0.2]. Interesting, since the converter specified in the link is *supposed to be* reside in the package `javafx.scene.layout`, which is not restricted API.

Does this converter still exist, and if so where can I find it, and if not is it ever coming back, and if so then what is a good ETA?

Comment: Looks like the class was moved to the `com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region` package in javafx 9 without depreciating it first... Probably not coming back anytime soon, since it's only used as part of the `BorderConverter` which never was public (it's package private). [Uses of the type `CornerRadii`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/class-use/CornerRadii.html)

Comment: See related issue [JDK-8096129](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096129). Indeed, it was moved to `com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region.CornerRadiiConverter` around Java 8u60.

Comment: @fabian and Jose Pereda - Thanks for your reply. Based on the description in the JDK-8096129 bug report, it appears that a decision was made to consider the converter to be an 'internal utility class' that should not be made public. That's fine, but then why can't Oracle do the full job and remove the web page that caused me to waste several hours pounding sand, and your time to answer my question. But that's not your issue, and thanks again for the reply

Comment: They don't remove the web page because someone may need the documentation for that version of JavaFX. I mean, even [documentation for Java 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/overview-summary.html) is still available online; older versions can apparently be downloaded from some archives. You need to look at the documentation for the version you're using: [JDK 10 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html).

Comment: @slaw - Fair comment, and in retrospect it makes sense to keep the older material around for cases where older jdk's are in play. My complaint was due to the time/effort wasted on trying to find a tool that appeared to be available but in the end proved to have disappeared. But that's all a lot of noise. Thanks for your reply.